# chartJS pie chart not updating after axios GET

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

In my Vue app I'm loading a page and it grabs some data from my Flask backend. I draw a bunch of elements and I also draw a pie chart based on an array of 3 values returned from the backend. When I get the response I update `this.pie_data` and I thought this would update in my template to reflect the pie chart. It renders the elements that get set in `this.nvrs` so not sure why it doesn't work for my pie chart.

Appreciate the help.

**Template**

```
<div class="box">
  <p class="title">System Overview</p>
  <chart :type="'pie'": data=chartData></chart>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Chart from 'vue-bulma-chartjs'

export default {
  name: 'NVR_Overview',
  components: {
    Chart,
  },
  data: () => ({
    nvrs: [],
    // Health, Down, Warn
    pie_data: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    goToNVR (nvrId)
    {
      let wpsId = this.$route.params['wpsId']

      let path = '/wps/' + wpsId + '/nvr/' + nvrId
      this.$router.push(path)
    },
  },
  created ()
  {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/wps/' + this.$route.params['wpsId'])
      .then(response =>
      {
        this.nvrs = response.data['nvr_list']
        this.pie_data = response.data['pie_data']
        console.log(this.pie_data)
      })
      .catch(e =>
      {
        console.log(e)
      })
  },
  computed: {
    chartData ()
    {
      return {
        labels: ['Healthy', 'Down', 'Warning'],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: this.pie_data,
            backgroundColor: ['#41B482', '#ff4853', '#FFCE56'],
          },
        ],
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: What are the vue dev tools saying?

Comment: @connexo  It shows a 'props' section and if i drill down, it has the data from my backend that I expect. The pie chart isn't getting rendered even though it has values for it. If i hardcode a value in the data: section then when I reload the page it renders.

Comment: change to `<chart :type="'pie'" :data="chartData"></chart>` then try again.

Comment: @Sphinx I tried that and no difference I'm afraid

Comment: add `console.log(this.pie_data)` to `chartData()`, then check whether computed property=chartData is triggered correctly. Did you post full codes for `created()`? I suspected the issue is caused by the context.

Comment: @Sphinx It says this in the console[1, 2, 3, __ob__: Observer]

Comment: when `axios.get` finished, does the computed property=chartData is updated (it print out `this.pie_data` in the console?)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171360/discussion-between-cathaldcronin1-and-sphinx).

Comment: I created a pull request https://github.com/vue-bulma/chartjs/pull/24

Comment: @ittus So is it a bug? Am I doing everything correctly? Any timeline on when the fix will be pushed?

Comment: If so,  try this: change to `<chart ref="mychart" :type="'pie'": data=chartData></chart>`, then in the computed proprety=chartData, call `this.$refs.mychart.update()`

Comment: `this.$refs.mychart.resetChart()`

Comment: `this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.chart.resetChart();
      })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** 
Copy old chart data reference when you make the change (old data have Observer, so don't make completed new object), instead of using computed value, use watch:

```
<template>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="title">System Overview</p>
    <chart :type="'pie'" :data="chartData"></chart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import Chart from 'vue-bulma-chartjs'

export default {
  name: 'NVR_Overview',
  components: {
    Chart,
  },
  data: () => ({
    nvrs: [],
    // Health, Down, Warn
    pie_data: [],
    chartData: {
      labels: ['Healthy', 'Down', 'Warning'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [],
          backgroundColor: ['#41B482', '#ff4853', '#FFCE56'],
        },
      ]
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    goToNVR (nvrId)
    {
      let wpsId = this.$route.params['wpsId']

      let path = '/wps/' + wpsId + '/nvr/' + nvrId
      this.$router.push(path)
    },
  },
  created ()
  {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/wps/' + this.$route.params['wpsId'])
      .then(response =>
      {
        this.nvrs = response.data['nvr_list']
        this.pie_data = response.data['pie_data']
        console.log(this.pie_data)
      })
      .catch(e =>
      {
        console.log(e)
      })
  },
  watch: {
    pie_data (newData) {
      const data = this.chartData
      data.datasets[0].data = newData
      this.chartData = {...data}
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

You can check this problem on `vue-bulma-chartjs` repository  https://github.com/vue-bulma/chartjs/pull/24

**Solution 2**:
Add ref to chart

```
<chart ref="chart" :type="'pie'" :data="data"</chart>
```

then in script after you assign data:

```
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.chart.resetChart();
  })
```

Comment: That works, will mark as correct. I used the second one you posted.

`
this.pie_data = response.data['pie_data']
this.$nextTick(() => { this.$refs.nvrchart.resetChart(); })
`

Which solution is better and why?

Comment: Solution 1 better. For second solution, you need to know there is a method called `resetChart` in `vue-bulma-chartjs` (which is not good for open-close principle - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)